# How can I make an array for each value of an enum in Rust?

Tags: rust

For each value of my enum, there's a bunch of informations that get accessed very regularly during calculations.
To potentially gain in efficiency and code clarity at the same time, I'd like to be able to use something like `data[Enum::Value].variable` to access this data (the data is static, with the array global and initialized at compile-time).

To achieve this, I've defined

```
enum Values {
  Value1 = 0,
  Value2 = 1,
}
```

Etc.
But doing `data[Values::Value1].variable` doesn't work ; so how can I achieve this ?

Edit : You can simply cast the enum value to usize.